# Why does python's "gc.collect()" not work as expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection

Here is my test code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import gc
import ctypes

name = "a" * 50
name_id = id(name)
del name
gc.collect()
print(ctypes.cast(name_id, ctypes.py_object).value)
```

output:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

In my opinion, `gc.collect()` should clean the variable `name` and it's value,
but why can I get value with `name_id` after `gc.collect()` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't *expect* `gc.collect()` to do *anything* here. `gc` simply controls the cyclic garbage collector, which is an auxilliary garbage collector because CPython uses reference counting for its main memory management strategy. The cyclic garbage collector handles reference cycles, there *are no reference cycles here* so `gc.collect` won't do anything.

> In my opinion, gc.collect() should clean the variable name and it's
> value,

That is simply not how Python works. The *variable* ceased to exist with `del name`, but the *object* continues to exist, in this case, due to compiler optimizations. Python variables are not like C variables, they aren't chunks of memory, *they are names that refer to objects in a particular namespace*.

In any case, disassembling the code will give you some insight here:

```
In [1]: import dis

In [2]: dis.dis("""
   ...: import gc
   ...: import ctypes
   ...:
   ...: name = "a" * 50
   ...: name_id = id(name)
   ...: del name
   ...: gc.collect()
   ...: print(ctypes.cast(name_id, ctypes.py_object).value)
   ...: """)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              4 IMPORT_NAME              0 (gc)
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (gc)

  3           8 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             12 IMPORT_NAME              1 (ctypes)
             14 STORE_NAME               1 (ctypes)

  5          16 LOAD_CONST               2 ('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
             18 STORE_NAME               2 (name)

  6          20 LOAD_NAME                3 (id)
             22 LOAD_NAME                2 (name)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             26 STORE_NAME               4 (name_id)

  7          28 DELETE_NAME              2 (name)

  8          30 LOAD_NAME                0 (gc)
             32 LOAD_METHOD              5 (collect)
             34 CALL_METHOD              0
             36 POP_TOP

  9          38 LOAD_NAME                6 (print)
             40 LOAD_NAME                1 (ctypes)
             42 LOAD_METHOD              7 (cast)
             44 LOAD_NAME                4 (name_id)
             46 LOAD_NAME                1 (ctypes)
             48 LOAD_ATTR                8 (py_object)
             50 CALL_METHOD              2
             52 LOAD_ATTR                9 (value)
             54 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             56 POP_TOP
             58 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             60 RETURN_VALUE
```

So, when your code block was *compiled*, the CPython compiler noticed that `"a"*50` could be turned into a constant, and so it did. It stores constants for code objects until that code object doesn't exist any more (in this case, when the interpreter exist). Since this code object will maintain a reference to this string object, it will exist the entire time.

So, more explicitely:

```
In [4]: code = compile("""name = "a" * 50""", filename='foo', mode='exec')

In [5]: code
Out[5]: <code object <module> at 0x7ff7c12495d0, file "foo", line 1>

In [6]: code.co_consts
Out[6]: ('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', None)
```

Note also that Python memory management is complex and pretty opaque. All objects are handled on a privately managed heap. Just because an object is "released" doesn't mean that the runtime won't simply re-used that bit of memory for objects of the same type (or other suitable types) as needed. Look at this:

```
In [1]: class Foo: pass

In [2]: import ctypes

In [3]: foo = Foo()

In [4]: id(foo)
Out[4]: 140559250737552

In [5]: del foo

In [6]: foo2 = Foo()

In [7]: id(foo2)
Out[7]: 140559250737680

In [8]: ctypes.cast(140559250737552, ctypes.py_object).value
Out[8]: <prompt_toolkit.lexers.pygments.RegexSync at 0x7fd68035c990>

In [9]: id(foo2)
Out[9]: 140559250737680

In [10]: del foo2

In [11]: ctypes.cast(140559250737680, ctypes.py_object).value
Out[11]: <prompt_toolkit.lexers.pygments.PygmentsLexer at 0x7fd68035ca10>
```

Notice how you are able to recover *some objects* in these cases, because the ipython interactive shell is creating objects all the time, and the internal heap is happy to re-use that memory.

Look what happens in a more bare-bones REPL:

```
(base) juanarrivillaga@50-254-139-253-static% python
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 07:22:35)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> i = id(foo)
>>> del foo
>>> ctypes.cast(i, ctypes.py_object).value
zsh: segmentation fault  python
```

So yeah. More what one might *expect*, we tried to access a part of memory that had been not only reclaimed by the internal heap, but freed by the Python process, and thus, we got a segmentation fault.

Comment: I have tried like this:    n = 50,  name = "a" * n.  In this case, name is not in co_consts, but I can also get value by name_id

Comment: @olivetree123 yes, **so what**? The Python interpreter is free to re-use memory if it please or not. In this case, that id was sent back to the heap, and it wasn't deallocated. That is entirely up to many various optimizations that exist for built-in types in the privately managed heap. Try it again after 10 minutes of allocating similar sized strings or other objects and you may get a segfault.  For example, I get a bus error when I just tried it. What is it you are trying to understand, fundamentally?