# How to clear memory of object during for loop on python

Tags: python, loops, memory

I want to clear memory during for loop. 
I tried `del`and `gc.collect`, but I coudn't clear memory. 
Code:

```
def memory_usage(message: str = 'debug'):
    # current process RAM usage
    p = psutil.Process()
    rss = p.memory_info().rss / 2 ** 20 # Bytes to MB
    print(f"[{message}] memory usage: {rss: 10.5f} MB")

all_cosines = []
for i in range(len(split_length)):
    if split_length[i] == split_length[-1]:
        sim = cosine_similarity(df, df.loc[split_length[i]:])
    else:
        sim = cosine_similarity(df, df.loc[split_length[i]:split_length[i+1]])
    memory_usage('#1')
    sim_list = [i for i in sim]
    all_cosines.extend(sim_list)
    del sim
    del sim_list
    gc.collect()
    memory_usage('#2')
```

Result : 
[#1] memory usage:  28983.18359 MB 
[#2] memory usage:  29012.25781 MB

Is there any possible way to clear memory during loop?

Comment: python does avoid returning memory to the OS in most cases.  it does however reuse the memory it grabbed.  If truly require lower level management, you can look into c extensions (and possibly cython).  That does not really apply to your case since you are extending that all_cosines list rather than removing all refs to your python objects.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64363771/17457042

Comment: Whay is the memory usage if you change the entire inner loop to `all_cosines += [cosine_similarity(df, df.loc[split_length[i]:]) if split_length[i] == split_length[-1]:] else cosine_similarity(df, df.loc[split_length[i]:split_length[i+1]])`